# the prediction function gives the same output everytime

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)).astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
def larger_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
model = larger_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Large CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))

model.save('good_model.h5')
print("Model saved")
```

After running this code, we get a '.h5' model, then to [predict this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ynZt.png) 
i added this code:

```
import cv2
model = load_model('good_model.h5')
file = cv2.imread('screenshot.png')
file = cv2.resize(file, (28, 28))
file = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
file = file.reshape((-1, 28, 28,1))
result = model.predict(file)
print(result[0])
t = (np.argmax(result[0]))
print("I predict this number is a:", t)
```

But I always get the same answer which is 4. above I tried to load the image with cv and convert it to gray and then reshape to the size of the input. It takes the input correctly but the answer is always the same no matter what image I give it as input

Comment: How did you get on with the assistance given below, Karan?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert the image before prediction. Once you invert the image, it will predict correctly. The given example is predicting as "2" but I checked with other images such as "7" and it is correctly predicting.

```
file = cv2.bitwise_not(file)
```

Other than the above, I made one change. I imported modules from Tensorflow 2.x. Please check the full code [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Mnist_prediction.ipynb).